# rfkill list all - It's showing me only bluetooth and nothing about wireless. ,wifi not working, ubuntu 20.04 - legion y530

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, realtek

I have been using 18.04 on my y530 at times since an year.
I decided to upgrade to 20.04 and since then i wasn't able to access wifi.
Initially, it showed no networks available. So i re-installed my realtek 8822be driver from this link:

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88

(I've blacklisted my older driver rtw_pci in blacklist.conf)

But it didn't work out.
Then, i installed a later version of kernel. 5.7.1 and booted from there. No change, and now when i boot from kernel 5.4. The wifi option isn't available.
Thanks in advance for the help. I'm still learning ubuntu(college undergrad). :)

Here is rfkill list:

```
rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Here is lspci -knn:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad E595 [17aa:b023]
    Kernel modules: rtw_8822be
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
```

Comment: @ThomasWard that solution will not help the rtl8822be, it is used for rtl8812au, rtl8814au, and rtl8821au  I would suggest that the asker remove the blacklist then reboot and run `rfkill list && lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net` again.  Also post results from terminal for `mokutil --sb-state` as Secure Boot will keep the github modules from loading

Comment: Does it show up after running `sudo modprobe rtw_8822be`?